# One liner to see if grep returned something?

Tags: grep, xargs

I'm trying to check if a machine is a ThinkPad or not using something like this:

```
sudo dmidecode | grep ThinkPad
```

I want the end result return true or false (or 1/0).

I'm thinking the solution might be something like this:

```
sudo dmidecode | grep -c ThinkPad | test xargs -gt 0
```

But I'm not sure how to properly use `xargs` here.

Comment: @don_crissti I don't see how I could use any of those answers without creating a shell script. I think this is different because answers are specifically one-liners for command line.

Comment: It's exactly the same - and your answer here proves that beyond any doubt - it's almost the same as _derobert_'s answer there but instead of `if...then...else` you're using `&&` and `||`.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Just tack the exit status check after `grep`, it will always get the exit status from the last command of the pipeline by default:

```
sudo dmidecode | grep -q ThinkPad; echo $?
```

Use `-q` to suppress any output from `grep` as we are interested in exit status only.

---

You can use command grouping if you fancy, but this is somewhat redundant here:

```
sudo dmidecode | { grep -q ThinkPad; echo $? ;}
```

Comment: I'm expecting to see 1 with this command but it returns 0

Comment: @PhilipKirkbride Whats the output of `sudo dmidecode | grep ThinkPad`?

Comment: It returns two lines with the word ThinkPad

Comment: @PhilipKirkbride The pattern is there...why would you think that `grep` would return 1? 0 means success (pattern found for `grep`), 1 means failure. Exit status is different from the Truthy-Falsy concept, actually the reverse.

Comment: ah that makes sense. This will work than.

Answer (score 13):

If you're going to use this an shell script with an `if` check, just use `-q` as heemayl suggested:

```
if sudo dmidecode | grep -q Thinkpad
then
    echo "I'm a Thinkpad"
fi
```

Since the `if` block checks the command's exit status, we can rely on `grep`'s exit status directly instead of printing `$?` and the comparing it to something else.

Answer (score 7):

Inspired by [Heemayl's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/359405/16792):

```
sudo dmidecode | grep -q ThinkPad && echo true || echo false
```

This will return true if ThinkPad is found by grep and false if not.

Comment: Philip, There's a caveat here... The portion after `||` will be executed if any of `grep` or `echo true` returns exit status non-zero... Although practically, the probability of failure of `echo` is nearly zero...

Answer (score 1):

Using `test` and `command substitution`,

```
test -n "$(sudo dmidecode | grep Thinkpad)"
```

also,

```
[ -n "$(sudo dmidecode | grep Thinkpad)" ]
```

Comment: Using `test` here is completey redundant, and a common antipattern. Pretty much every Unix command sets its exit code to indicate success or failure; learn to use that instead of checking whether something was printed (which will be false in many common success scenarios, and could be true even if a command failed).

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo dmidecode | grep -c ThinkPad | xargs test 0 -lt
```

You need to rearrange the `xargs` and `test` command as also it's operands to be able to get what you want. This will return a true status if there are nonzero (>0) ThinkPad comprising lines.

Alternatively, if you want retain the operand order of test command you can do

```
sudo dmidecode | grep -c ThinkPad | xargs -I \{\} test \{\} -gt 0
```

And then, in both the commands, check for the `$?` variable's value to determine the fate of grep's success / failure, as follows:

```
if sudo dmidecode | grep -c ThinkPad | xargs -I \{\} test \{\} -gt 0; then
   echo "success hooray!"
else 
   echo nothing
fi
```